# i wrote a c program of creating a string length counter in C but the code isnt running

Tags: c

```
//write a c program to make your own version of strlen from <string.h>

#include<stdio.h>

int strlength(char * str){
    char *ptr=str;
    int len=0;
    while(*ptr!='\0'){
        len++;
        str++;
    }
    return len;
}

int main(){
    char str[]="bishal";
    int l=strlength(str);
    printf("the length of the string is %d",l);
    return 0;
}
```

this was the code i was writing and i dont know why but my text editors wont run it for me plus i cannot see any error on the screen[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSawd.png)

the only error i can see is when i try to run the same in an online compiler , the error looks like this     /tmp/zcp4rImwpV.o

if anyone knows the answer to my question then please help.

Comment: `/tmp/zcp4rImwpV.o` is only a filename, can you provide the full error output?

Comment: It's an infinite loop because you're incrementing `str` but testing `*ptr`. `ptr` never changes.

Comment: thanks for helping , now i understand what i did wrong but i still want to know the reason why my editor was not showing any output or error , was it because of the infite loop

Comment: Your code's syntax is correct, so most editors won't flag this code. It will compile and execute, it just won't ever reach the `printf` call. If you had put a `printf` inside the loop, you would realize pretty quickly what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of incrementing `str` in your function `strlength`, increment `ptr`. Your `while` loop is running infinitely because `ptr` never reaches `'\0'`. Like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int strlength(char * str){
    char *ptr=str;
    int len=0;
    while(*ptr!='\0'){
        len++;
        ptr++;
    }
    return len;
} 

int main(){
    char str[]="bishal";
    int l=strlength(str);
    printf("the length of the string is %d",l);
    return 0;
}
```